# Listing username with bid items - PHP

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm trying to make a simple auction website. I think I've run into my first problem.

What I'm trying to do is let a registered user add an item to the auction. I can do this just fine. However, I also need to keep track of the user that put the item up for bidding. I thought I could get the accountid by inserting the accountid from the current session into my table, but I keep getting an error saying accountid is an unknown column in my field list.

Here is the code where I create the table.

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE biditems (
    itemid INT(100) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    accountid INT(100),
    biditem VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    biddesc tinytext
    )";
```

And to add the items.

```
 $accountid=$_SESSION['accountid'];
    $item=$_POST['item'];
    $description=$_POST['description'];

    $sql= "INSERT INTO biditems (accountid, biditem, biddesc) VALUES
    ('$accountid', '$item', '$description')";
```

Comment: Do you have a column in your table which is named as `accountid` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks fine. I have also tested it.
Did you double check that the structure of your table is correct?

If you can insert a row via phpMyAdmin or the MySQL Workbench try this and afterwards run a select query like

```
$rows = "SELECT * FROM biditems";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Something like this just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should make some sql injection escape first. And if you did it - you should add the variables properly. I did not wrote you some injection escape. You can see sprintf instructions for example.

```
<?php
$accountid=$_SESSION['accountid'];
$item=$_POST['item'];
$description=$_POST['description'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO biditems (accountid, biditem, biddesc) VALUES
('" . $accountid . "', '" . $item . "', '" . $description . "')";
```